# Installing a standalone python module

Tags: python, pip

I am extremely new in python so i cant figure out a way to install a standalone python module hosted by a third party. Ex https://github.com/cvangysel/gitexd-drupalorg/tree/master/drupalorg

How to install this specific python module `DrupalHash` . Should i use pip ? I tried to read the documentation [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) but i could not quite get it.

Any help ?

Comment: Me also same issue, are u persuing oscp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as the linked repo doesn't contain a `setup.py`, which would be required to install it with `pip` or `easy_install`, and the last commit was over 4 years ago, I'd just copy the `drupalpass.py` file into your local project and use it with a simple `from drupalpass import DrupalHash`.

Answer (score -1):

The module you are linking doesn't seem to be available on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), you will need to clone the repository to use the library.

For packages that may be available on PyPI, you can install pip:

```
easy_install pip
```

Then, you will be able to install your packages:

```
pip install *package name*
```

Comment: FWIW, it would've been better if you had edited your old answer and then un-deleted it, rather than creating a new answer.

Comment: @user312016 but since this package is not present in the pip repository once i clone it how do i install it ?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the advice, I'll do that next time.

Comment: @rockstar The easiest way would by to include the package directly in your project.